# Send email from SQL Server 2005 / 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, email

I have to send emails from SQL Server 2005 or 2008. I have done this in the past with additional stored procedures (`sp_send_html_mail`) and complex configuration / activations. Is there standard build-in stored procedure which sends email via SMTP (not MAPI/CAPI/Outlook profiles)? I found `sp_send_dbmail` on this topic but not sure is it the only one and what security issues are possible (except spam)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `sp_send_dbmail` is the one to use for both SQL Sever 2005 and 2008.

You will need to make sure it has been configured on your server.  It's been a while since I did such a config, but if memory serves me correctly, it is off by default.  Have a look at the MS docs for that process, [Configure Database Mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245116.aspx).  Setting an SMTP server is doable as well.  There are lots of options in there so give it a thorough review.

If you are worried about unwanted use of that sp you can use roles and/or execute permission to limit access to it.  From the MS docs on troubleshooting dbmail:

> To send Database mail, users must be a user in the msdb database and a
>   member of the DatabaseMailUserRole database role in the msdb database.
>   To add msdb users or groups to this role use SQL Server Management
>   Studio or execute the following statement for the user or role that
>   needs to send Database Mail.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'DatabaseMailUserRole'
    ,@membername = '<user or role name>';
GO
```